# MapView android

Tags: android, view, dictionary

I have the Google Map API key and I have the Google Maps Android API v2 turend ON`

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`
```

But I am still not getting gray lines in the application.

any advice?

thanks in advance

Comment: post your log and code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial will guide you to right place...

[Google map v2 tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

[Tutorial 2](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/developing-with-google-maps-v2-android)

Comment: I did all the steps described but the weird thing that i noticed is taht my API key is different from any other I've seen in any example.
AIzaSyAZQRd0p2e37HFjda7zmj1BhiyzJSz0_-4 does this look valid to you?

also please consoder that I am using google api 2.2 not 4

Comment: No it will not be like this...Just give me a hint how  you get this api key..? Or which sample you followed to get this?

Comment: 9D:85:8D:F5:F4:9C:7E:D0:5E:07:3B:0F:B1:50:CF:05:CC:FB:DB:06;package_name

Comment: Yes thats the way...Have you enable the services in Google API console?

Comment: yes just the Google Maps Android API v2. I am really confused have tried everything. I sick of the gray lines :)

Comment: Try to swicth on this "Google maps v2" too and follow this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: Please check your user permission "com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps" instead you have to give your registered package name...

Comment: had some more problems but all solved now , thank you very much for the support , i appreciate it